# Can any external stents (or something like this) be used to solve aorto-venous conflict (May-Thurner syndrome)?

Tags: blood-circulation, cardiovascular-disease, venous-system, abdominal, stents

Is there can be used any external stents or something like this to solve aorto-venous conflict ([May-Thurner syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/May%E2%80%93Thurner_syndrome)) or [Nutcracker syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nutcracker_syndrome)?

For example, a stent consisting of polytetrafluoroethylene, which is placed on top of the vein so that it is not constricted. Performing an open abdominal surgery.

Because **Internal stenting** (common angioplasty and stenting) is subject to risks:

- of compression of the stent - because the stent cannot be very durable due to the limitations of wire thickness.
- and migration of the stent, in which case it is necessary to take anticoagulants for life

In opposite, **External stent** doesn't require to take anticoagulants at all, and can be very durable (high radial stability).

PS

Any references to scientific papers are welcome.

Comment: Angioplasty and stenting is a common treatment for May-Thurner. However, the stents aren't external. They're placed inside the vein as with most stents, and open abdominal surgery isn't required. That's readily available information found easily with a web search. Are you specifically asking about some sort of external stenting?

Comment: @Carey Gregory **Internal stent** can be compressed or can migrate then it is necessary  to take anticoagulants for life.  In opposite, **External stent** doesn't require to take anticoagulants at all, and can be very durable (high radial stability).

Comment: @Alex Although I don't know if it applies to all cases, it looks like the stents used in these procedures are shape-memory stents like WALLSTENT (made of a material like nitinol). Those stents are amazingly difficult to compress, and even when compressed with strong force their shape memory means they re-expand. I also can't imagine a stent like that ever migrating unless it was deployed in a completely inappropriate diameter vessel - can you provide an example?

Comment: @Bryan Krause **1.** If the stent diameter is less than the diameter of the vessel - it can migrate. **2.** If the diameter of the stent is larger than the diameter of the vessel, it may later increase in diameter (by stretching the vein), shrink in size - the edge of the stent will leave the compression site - the stent will not be holded by compressions and may migrate. **3.** A very strong compression can immediately permanently squeeze the stent, the stent will lengthen and its part will protrude into the lumen of the intersection of the veins where it will not grow into the vessel.

Comment: @Bryan Krause  Usually, you cannot determine the diameter of a non-uniformly compressed vessel with absolute precision.

Comment: True, but those are fairly rare complications occurring when the stent is improperly placed. In the normal healing process the stent ends up embedded in the vascular wall. I can't see physically how an external stent would work.

Comment: @Bryan Krause But is there any evidence or statistical studies on how long does it take for the stent to grow, and that with an ingrown stent, there is no need to take anticoagulant / antiplatelet therapy for life? The External stent is simply a flexible or closed case consisting of polytetrafluoroethylene. **It is logical** that in case of internal vessel blockage (cholesterol plaques) - it is necessary to solve the problem inside the vessel - an internal stent. And with external compression (aorto-venous conflicts)- it is necessary to solve the problem outside the vessel - an external stent.

Comment: @Alex That may be your logic, but that doesn't mean it's correct. How do you expect to get an external tube over a vein, presuming you are thinking of the sort used for bypass grafts?

Comment: @Bryan Krause Like this https://hsto.org/webt/ch/lc/xa/chlcxaatmagupv9xrkdoanllgam.jpeg but using to protect an existing vessel rather than bypass grafts, which can be put on a vein by using a cut in the protective cable https://hsto.org/webt/rm/5b/h9/rm5bh9pzga977_r6vijhf145mbw.jpeg then internal angioplasty can be performed.

Comment: @Alex I don't think cutting a metal stent like that is a good idea. The lattice isn't designed to be broken, it gets the strength from being complete.

Comment: @Bryan Krause There is no metal stent on image. There is polytetrafluoroethylene external stent. And it must be cut during production.

Comment: @Bryan Krause Also the main disadvantage of most internal stents (for example Wallstent) is that they do not have a beveled edge. Compression very often occurs very closely at the intersection of two veins, there is no right angle, so even when a stent is inserted correctly - bottom edge of the stent will always protrude into the intersection of the veins (1-2 mm) - it will not grow into the vessel completely. Should the patient in this case receive life-long therapy with anticoagulants or antiplatelet agents?

Comment: @Alex Okay, perhaps you have some more background on this external stent idea than I am aware of. In any case, this question should probably be closed. It looks like you're asking about a hypothetical idea that you know hasn't been tested it.

Comment: @Bryan Krause For example:   https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4892158/

Comment: @Alex That is not a PTFE external stent, it's a PTFE graft. They've completely severed the vessel and grafted on a bypass.